# Java license not for commercial use?

Tags: java, android

I have the following situation. I just installed the latest version of java but in the license is standing that this software is for personal use only.

My question: Am I allowed to publish a native android app (written in Java or Kotlin) or any other program that is written in java? Or do I have to get some special licenses for this?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a legal / licensing question.

Comment: Ok, but there are over 40 people, which are interested in this question. And I do not know any other platform for this question. I am sorry.

Comment: That's fine.  But here is the thing: nobody here is *qualified* to answer this question.  So you cannot trust any answers that you get here.  And I have seen some dangerously incorrect answers offered here on licensing topics.  Advice / opinions that could end up with you on the wrong end of a lawsuit if you believed them.  You are better off asking these questions somewhere else.

Comment: FWIW: **my understanding** of the Oracle license is that it is about the *acts of using* Java and the ways that you are permitted to use it, not the *work products of that use*.   And the FAQ says this: "This license permits personal use, development, testing, prototyping, demonstrating and some other uses at no cost."   Parse that and interpret that for yourself.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation, but I am using the openJDK which comes with Android Studio. So there shouldn't be any license problems but please correct me if I should be wrong.

Comment: Use of OpenJDK is covered by the OpenJDK license.  It is GPL 2.0 "with classpath exception".  There is no restriction on commercial use.  And the "classpath exception" means that you are not required to open-source your code.  The OpenJDK license is very different to the Oracle JDK license(s).

Comment: But seriously, if you want to understand a software license, the first thing you need to do is to read it.  Or, at least, read the associated FAQs.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are using Oracle JDK 8. Use https://adoptopenjdk.net/ instead.

Comment: Ok but I just wanted to know if I could publish an app on the play store with JDK 8 as a little programmer with no published app.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this was a silly mistake because I noticed that android studio has his own JDK if you go to project structure. So I will use this one.